# python как корректно спарсить содержимое блока <div содержащего множество других <div>

Tags: css, python-3.x, парсер, requests, lxml

Есть допустим обычный сайт букмекера: https://melbet.ru/live/football/

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
from loguru import logger


url = 'https://melbet.ru/live/football/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(response.content, 'lxml')
results = soup.find(id="blockContent")   # блок div по его id 
print(result)         # <-- не выводит все блоки <div> содержащие информацию об внутренних div
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: по сути даже содержимое блока div не выводит все внурение блоки /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать приведенный ниже пример или покурите в сторону `selenium` .

> [Источнику](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1349481/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0-https-www-wildberries-ru-catalog-0-search-aspx/1361129#1361129) не забудьте сказать спасибо

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
session = HTMLSession()
url = 'https://melbet.ru/live/football/'
response = session.get(url)
response.html.render(sleep=3, keep_page=True, scrolldown=2)
soup = Soup(
    response.html.raw_html,
    'html.parser'
)
block_id = soup.find_all('div', class_='kofsTableLigaName')
print(block_id)
#[<div class="kofsTableLigaName"><span class="sportIco s1"></span>Чемпионат Англии. Премьер-лига</div>, <div class="kofsTableLigaName"><span class="sportIco s1"></span>Чемпионат Англии. Чемпионшип</div>, <div class="kofsTableLigaName"><span class="sportIco s1"></span>Чемпионат Израиля. Премьер-лига</div>, <div class="kofsTableLigaName"><span class="sportIco s1"></span>Чемпионат Ирака</div>, <div class="kofsTableLigaName"><span class="sportIco s1"></span>Чемпионат Северной Ирландии. Премьер-лига</div>, <div class="kofsTableLigaName"><span class="sportIco s1"></span>Чемпионат Танзании. Премьер-лига</div>, <div class="kofsTableLigaName"><span class="sportIco s1"></span>Чемпионат Англии. Северная Премьер-лига</div>, <div class="kofsTableLigaName"><span class="sportIco s1"></span>Чемпионат Палестины</div>, <div class="kofsTableLigaName"><span class="sportIco s1"></span>Чемпионат Англии. Истмийская Лига. Премьер-дивизион</div>, <div class="kofsTableLigaName"><span class="sportIco s1"></span>Чемпионат Англии. Лига 1</div>, <div class="kofsTableLigaName"><span class="sportIco s1"></span>Чемпионат Англии. Лига 2</div>, <div class="kofsTableLigaName"><span class="sportIco s1"></span>Чемпионат Англии. Национальная лига</div>, <div class="kofsTableLigaName"><span class="sportIco s1"></span>Чемпионат Англии. Южная Премьер-лига. Центр</div>, <div class="kofsTableLigaName"><span class="sportIco s1"></span>Чемпионат Англии. Южная Премьер-лига. Юг</div>, <div class="kofsTableLigaName"><span class="sportIco s1"></span>Чемпионат Англии. Истмийская Лига. 1-й дивизион. Север</div>, <div class="kofsTableLigaName"><span class="sportIco s1"></span>Чемпионат Англии. Истмийская Лига. 1-й дивизион. Юг</div>, <div class="kofsTableLigaName"><span class="sportIco s1"></span>Чемпионат Англии. Северная лига. Дивизион 1</div>, <div class="kofsTableLigaName"><span class="sportIco s1"></span>Чемпионат Англии. Северная Национальная лига</div>, <div class="kofsTableLigaName"><span class="sportIco s1"></span>Чемпионат Англии. Южный дивизион 1</div>]
```

Comment: Все круто , все четко ) Спасибо и Вам милый человек ))